# Sending the body data to an external API node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, api

I've been trying to send some data that I received in 'request body' to an external API that I'm calling using fetch in node js but something goes wrong and I don't know whether the data I'm sending is being received properly by that external API or not. This is how my controller looks:

```
'use strict';

var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
  fetch = require('node-fetch'),
  Fault = mongoose.model('Fault');

exports.register_a_fault = function(req, res) {
  var new_fault = new Fault(req.body);
  new_fault.save(function(err, fault) {
    if (err)
      res.send(err);
    console.log(fault.machineId);
    res.json({dataId:req.body.dataId});

    fetch('http://localhost/fault', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
      body: '{"machineId":req.body.machineId,"start":req.body.startDateTime,"clientEmail":"a@xyz.in"}'
        }).then(function(res){
          console.log(res);
        }).catch(err => {});

  });
};
```

The schema for the register_a_fault is

```
{
    "machineId":"test",
    "startDateTime":"2017-11-23 17:36:00",
    "endDateTime":"2017-11-23 17:46:00"
}
```

and the schema for the external fault API

```
{
    "machineId":"test",
    "start":"2017-11-23 17:36:00",
    "clientEmail":"a@xyz.in"
}
```

Comment: What response is the API giving you?  Is it giving you a particular response code (404, 500, etc)?

Comment: That's the problem sometimes it gives me 200 and sometimes 406 or even 500. When I try it with hardcoded data it hits perfectly and does what it's suppose to do